# java stream groupingBy + aggregate

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
public class Member {
  private String name;
  private String team;
  private List<String> tasks;
  ...
}
```

input list like:

```
member1, team1, [task1]
member2, team1, [task2]
member2, team1, [taks3]
member3, team2, [task4]
member3, team2, [task5, task6]
```

Try to group by team and aggregate the tasks for each member together, how to write the stream? The expected result is `Map<String, List<Member>>` like:

```
team1: [
  member1: [task1]
  member2: [task2, task3]
]
team2: [
  member3: [task4, task5, task6]
]
```

grouping by team is easy. The challenge is how to aggregate the tasks for each different member and still maintain the result as `Map>

**UPDATE:** This is the best I can do, but it's 2 steps. Can anyone merge these to one?

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Member m1 = new Member("member1", "team1", task("task1"));
    Member m2 = new Member("member2", "team1", task("task2"));
    Member m3 = new Member("member2", "team1", task("task3"));
    Member m4 = new Member("member3", "team2", task("task4"));
    Member m5 = new Member("member3", "team2", task("task5"));

    List<Member> list = Arrays.asList(m1, m2, m3, m4, m5);

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Map<String, Map<String, Optional<Member>>> result = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Member::getTeam,
                    Collectors.groupingBy(Member::getName, Collectors.reducing(
                            (member1, member2) -> {
                                member1.getTasks().addAll(member2.getTasks());
                                return member1;
                            }
                    ))));
    Map<String, List<Member>> result2 = result.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey(),
                    entry -> entry.getValue().values().stream()
                            .map(e -> e.get()).collect(Collectors.toList())));

    result2.entrySet().stream().forEach(System.out::println);

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Total:" + (end - start) + "ms");
}

private static List<String> task(String... tasks) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.addAll(list, tasks);
    return list;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show your attempt?

Comment: Why do "member2" and "member3" appear twice? If you have a dedicated `Member` object to represent each member, then each member should only be defined once. Otherwise what happens if "member2" is defined once in team1 and then the second time in team2?

Comment: it's already a simplified example, let's say the source of the list is from multiple upstream system which data is not aggregated. That's why mermber2 and member3 repeated.

Comment: Based on the output, the target return type should be `Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>`.

Answer (score 2):

The following collector combination should do just that.

I'm sure this is one good example of what's technically possible but not so much a good idea when it comes to readability.

```
List<Member> list = ...
Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> map = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Member::getTeam, 
            Collectors.groupingBy(Member::getName,
              Collectors.mapping(Member::getTasks,
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), 
                    (doubleList) -> doubleList.stream()
                      .flatMap(lst -> lst.stream())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()))))));
```

When tested with the following input (added constructor):

```
List<Member> list = Arrays.asList(
        new Member("name1", "team1", Arrays.asList("task1", "task11")),
        new Member("name1", "team1", Arrays.asList("task2", "task22")),
        new Member("name1", "team2", Arrays.asList("task1", "task11")));
```

The resulting map contains:

```
{team1={name1=[task1, task11, task2, task22]}, team2={name1=[task1, task11]}}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but the expected result structure is `Map<String, List<Member>> `

Comment: The example in your post shows Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>

Answer (score 1):

Your task consist of two steps: Grouping by team then grouping by member and merge their task.

Try this:

```
Map<String, List<Member>> result =
           members.stream()
                  .collect(groupingBy(Member::getTeam,
                           collectingAndThen(groupingBy(Member::getName,
                                        reducing(null, (m1, m2) -> {
                                            if (m1 == null) {
                                                return m2;
                                            }
                                            List<String> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
                                            tasks.addAll(m1.getTasks());
                                            tasks.addAll(m2.getTasks());
                                            m2.setTasks(tasks);
                                            return m2;
                                        })), map -> new ArrayList<>(map.values()))));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the expected return type is `Map<String, List<Member>> not  Map<String, Map<String, Member>>`

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using `Collectors.toMap` function.

In your example:

```
Map<String, Member> mapByTeams =
  listOfMembers.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Member::getTeam, Function.identity()));
```

Comment: This won't work when there are more than one `team` name. Also, this is not what the OP wanted